# setState is not setting sate, it is not working as expected after a get request in componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

I have 2 get request which return details that corresponds to a patient.

`First GET request` returns patient’s details and encrypted patientId, which is used on the Second GET request to get the patient’s name. I need to save both the value of get request into an `array in the state on patients: [{ }]` but that patient on state shows empty with what I've tried.

```
const getUserConfig = await axios.get(`/room/room01/userconfig`);
const uuId = getUserConfig.data.room01.patientId;
console.log(uuid) // is the patientId

`Returned Data`

{
  "room01": {
    "conditions": [
      "Fever”, “Headache”
    ],
    "room": "room01",
    "patientId": "e1040efd-dwe6-4956-a4g5-2a6caa6318f9",
    "observationLevel": "1",
  }
}
```

```
The `Second GET request`

let getPatientName = await axios.get(`/patient/${uuId}/name`);
console.log(getPatientName.data); // is the patient name
```

How I'm trying to save on state but isn't working

```
  this.setState({
            patients: [
                {
                    patientName: getPatientName.data,
                    label:  patientData.data.room01.label, 
                    observationLevel: patientData.data.room01.observationLevel,
                }
            ]
        });
```

What the state should be looking like after both GET requests, and I would like to keep adding new patient to the next index in the array on the next GET request.

```
    this.state = {
            patients: [
{patientName: ‘string’, room: `room01`, observationLevel: `1`, …..}
]
        };
```

Comment: You keep getting the keys wrong. If that API reply is correct, it's `getUserConfig.data.room01.patientId` (not `.patient`). And your `setState` tries getting `room02.nhsNumber` from what you say is a string? And I don't see a `label` in the API response.

Comment: @ChrisG Hi apologies, I've made the corrections here, the code has correct keys and it doesn't setstate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked: https://medium.com/@mirthfulnahid/using-the-spread-syntax-in-react-js-to-set-state-array-of-object-c47c631f64b0

```
const patientsArray = [{
            patientName: getPatientName.data,
            nhsNumber: patientData.data.room01.nhsNumber,
            label: patientData.data.room01.label,
            observationLevel: patientData.data.room01.observationLevel
        }];

        this.setState({
            patients: [...this.state.patients, ...patientsArray]})
```